# Django Rest Framework Invalid serialization

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serialize a dictionary into Relationship Serializer, the data gets serialized fine but the validator returns false

**RelationshipSerializer:**

```
class RelationshipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(read_only=False)
    related_user = UserSerializer(read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Relationship
        fields = (
            'user',
            'related_user',
        )
```

**View:**

```
related_user_id = body["related_user"]
related_user = models.User.objects.get(id=related_user_id)

user = self.get_object()

user_serializer = serializers.UserSerializer(user).data
related_user_serializer = serializers.UserSerializer(related_user).data

# user_serializer and related_user_serializer return valid data.

data = {"user": user_serializer, "related_user": related_user_serializer}

serializer = serializers.RelationshipSerializer(data=data)

# Serializer works fine, it prints out data correctly    

serializer.is_valid() # Returns false

return Response(serializer.data)
```

When I log `serializer.errors` I get

```
{
    "required": "This field is required.",
    "null": "This field may not be null.",
    "invalid": "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got {datatype}."
}
```

I tried setting my serializer fields to `null = True` and `required = False` but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try allow_blank and allow_null in serializer fiels:

```
user = UserSerializer(read_only=False, allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
related_user = UserSerializer(read_only=False, allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
```

Comment: I found my way to this answer when having `.is_valid()` return false. Indeed one of my fields was an empty string. But `allow_blank` does not seem to be a valid kwarg for the serializer constructor. I fixed the issue by changing the field on the model itself to have `allow_blank=True`, which fixed it.